# zoo/xts microsecond read issue

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, strptime

The data looks like

```
           Time  Set1    Set2   
10:19:38.551629 16234   16236   
10:19:41.408010 16234   16236   
10:19:47.264204 16234   16236
```

I am trying to load this into zoo.

```
orig <- read.zoo("~/sample.txt",sep="",header=TRUE,index.column=1,format="%H:%M:%S.%6f")

Error in read.zoo("~/sample.txt", sep = "", header = TRUE, index.column = 1,  : 
  index has 3 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 ...
```

I have checked all the relevant posts 
1. [R issue with rounding milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931972/r-issue-with-rounding-milliseconds)
2. [Milliseconds puzzle when calling strptime in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889554/milliseconds-puzzle-when-calling-strptime-in-r?lq=1)
3. [How to parse milliseconds in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds-in-r?rq=1)

However this does not help.
Any Suggestions

Comment: Notice that the answers to all those posts use `format = '%H:%M:%OS'` or `format = '%H:%M:%OS6'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the index to be a time class such as `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`.  Also, your `format` argument wasn't quite right.  Try this

```
read.zoo("~/sample.txt", header = TRUE, format="%H:%M:%OS", FUN=as.POSIXct)
```

Which, for the sample data provided, gives

```
read.zoo(text="           Time  Set1    Set2   
10:19:38.551629 16234   16236   
10:19:41.408010 16234   16236   
10:19:47.264204 16234   16236   ", header = TRUE, format="%H:%M:%OS", FUN=as.POSIXct)
#                            Set1  Set2
#2012-06-21 10:19:38.551629 16234 16236
#2012-06-21 10:19:41.408010 16234 16236
#2012-06-21 10:19:47.264204 16234 16236
```

Comment: Note that `read.zoo(..., tz = "")` or similar but using `tz="GMT"`, say, will cause `read.zoo` to default to POSIXct with the time zone indicated.

Comment: Set1  Set2
2012-06-22 10:19:38 16234 16236
2012-06-22 10:19:41 16234 16236
2012-06-22 10:19:47 16234 16236. I also set the options(digits=6), but still no microsecond timestamp in the read.zoo

Comment: `options(digits.secs=6)`. Run that, then you'll see microseconds.

Comment: Thanks GSee. Zoo seems to be pretty powerful.