# zoo and utc time with microseconds

Tags: r, time, utc, xts, zoo

The dataset has utc time with microseconds

```
TIME,DATA1,DATA2
1350359123.325330,661.00,765.00
1350359123.491836,661.00,765.50
```

However, I am unable to do the utc format conversion and microseconds at the same time.

I have already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136340/r-zoo-xts-microsecond-read-issue) but that had a different time format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `zoo` or `xts` for the *parsing* of the time:

```
R> as.POSIXct(c(1350359123.325330, 1350359123.491836), 
+             origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")
[1] "2012-10-16 03:45:23.325330 UTC" "2012-10-16 03:45:23.491836 UTC"
R>
```

Now, given `POSIXct` as time objects, you can create the `xts` or `zoo` object for the data part.