# R: xts timestamp differ from real data timestamp by 1 millisecond

Tags: r, xts

So I have the following data.

```
tt <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("2018-03-01 09:51:59.969", "2018-03-01 09:51:59.969", 
"2018-03-01 09:51:59.970", "2018-03-01 09:51:59.971", "2018-03-01 09:51:59.987", 
"2018-03-01 09:51:59.988"), Mid_Px = c(30755.5, 30755, 30755.5, 
30756, 30756.5, 30756.5)), .Names = c("Timestamp", "Mid_Px"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 85774:85779)
```

which looks like this:

```
                    Timestamp  Mid_Px
85774 2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 30755.5
85775 2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 30755.0
85776 2018-03-01 09:51:59.970 30755.5
85777 2018-03-01 09:51:59.971 30756.0
85778 2018-03-01 09:51:59.987 30756.5
85779 2018-03-01 09:51:59.988 30756.5
```

When I try to create an xts object out of it by using the code below, things start to go bad.

```
tt_ts <- strptime(tt[,1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
tt_ts
[1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 CST" "2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 CST" "2018-03-01 09:51:59.970 CST" "2018-03-01 09:51:59.971 CST" "2018-03-01 09:51:59.987 CST"
[6] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.988 CST"
xts(x=tt[,c(-1)], order.by=tt_ts)
                           [,1]
2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 30755.5
2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 30755.0
2018-03-01 09:51:59.970 30755.5
2018-03-01 09:51:59.970 30756.0
2018-03-01 09:51:59.986 30756.5
2018-03-01 09:51:59.987 30756.5
```

Notice that the milliseconds are incorrect in row 4,5 and 6.

What have I done wrong here ? How can I fix it to display the correct timestamp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [R issue with rounding milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931972/r-issue-with-rounding-milliseconds). One simple solution would be adding 0.5 ms as suggested there:

```
tt_ts <- strptime(tt[,1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") + 0.0005
xts::xts(x=tt[,c(-1)], order.by=tt_ts)
#                            [,1]
# 2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 30755.5
# 2018-03-01 09:51:59.969 30755.0
# 2018-03-01 09:51:59.970 30755.5
# 2018-03-01 09:51:59.971 30756.0
# 2018-03-01 09:51:59.987 30756.5
# 2018-03-01 09:51:59.988 30756.5
```

We can see this from a simple example:

```
st <- strptime("2018-03-01 09:51:59.971", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
format(st, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.971"
pt <- as.POSIXct(st)
format(pt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.970"
```

After conversion to `POSIXct` the ms is wrong. Increasing the output precision, we see that the floating point number used to represent the time is just below the required value, but R truncates the number instead of rounding it:

```
format(pt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.970999"
```

Shifting by one half of the required precision fixes this.

```
format(pt + 0.0005, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.971"
```

Generally, if *x* is a number with 3 decimal digits, any number within the open range (*x* - 0.0005, *x* + 0.0005) would be rounded to *x*. On truncation, that would still work for those within [*x*, *x* + 0.0005). But those within (*x* - 0.0005, *x*) would be represented by *x* - 0.001 as you observed. If we shift the relevant number by 0.0005 before truncation, we are speaking about the range (*x*, *x* + 0.001). All these numbers will be truncated to *x* as wanted.

I am excluding the points *x* ± 0.0005 since there are different rules for rounding them and the actual floating point number representing the time point will be a lot closer to the desired value than this.

**EDIT:** Concerning the question in the comments about taking differences: There it should not matter whether you add half a milli-second or not if you add it to both points. Example with a time point that needs adjustment on its own:

```
st1 <- strptime("2018-03-01 09:51:59.971", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
format(st1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")                              
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.970"
pt1 <- as.POSIXct(st1)                                          
format(pt1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")                              
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.970"
format(pt1 + 0.0005, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")                     
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.971"
```

And a time point that does not need adjustment:

```
st2 <- strptime("2018-03-01 09:51:59.969", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
format(st2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")                              
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.969"
pt2 <- as.POSIXct(st2)                                          
format(pt2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")                              
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.969"
format(pt2 + 0.0005, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")                     
#> [1] "2018-03-01 09:51:59.969"
```

Difference is the same independent of any adjustment:

```
difftime(pt1, pt2, "secs")                                      
#> Time difference of 0.001999855 secs
difftime(pt1 + 0.0005, pt2 + 0.0005, "secs")                    
#> Time difference of 0.001999855 secs
```

Comment: Is there a standard solution ? Because I am dealing with million lines of data. I am not sure whether `+0.0005` is appropriate for all timestamps. Thanks.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF From my point of view this is general, see extended answer.

Comment: I do have one question: if i were to calculate the time difference between timestamp in this case, shall i do `difftime(t1+0.0005, t2+0.0005, units="secs")` ? Is it necessary to add `0.0005` in both timestamps to ensure the time difference is calculated correctly?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF It is not necessary to add 0.0005 if you are taking differences, c.f. my expanded answer.