# R lubridate ymd_hms millisecond diff

Tags: r, lubridate

Is there something I'm missing in time conversions? Very simple example:

```
library(lubridate)
time <- "2019-01-14 10:58:23.438000"

op <- options(digits.secs=6)
ymd_hms(time, tz = "Europe/Helsinki")
[1] "2019-01-14 10:58:23.437 EET"

ymd_hms(time)
[1] "2019-01-14 10:58:23.437 UTC"
```

Why is milliseconds one off here? Doesn't seem to be rounding issue?

While this seems to work:

```
time <- "2019-01-14 10:58:23.123456"

op <- options(digits.secs=6)

ymd_hms(time)
[1] "2019-01-14 10:58:23.123456 UTC"
```

SessionInfo

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Finnish_Finland.1252  LC_CTYPE=Finnish_Finland.1252    LC_MONETARY=Finnish_Finland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=Finnish_Finland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 magrittr_1.5   tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.2.0     Rcpp_1.0.0     stringi_1.2.4  stringr_1.3.1
```

Comment: Running your code in my machine (I also have version 1.7.4 of `lubridate`) does not even output the milliseconds. I get only: `"2019-01-14 10:58:23 EET"` and `"2019-01-14 10:58:23 UTC"`.

Comment: I added options part, I probably had changed that before I ran this.

Comment: ok, now I get the same output as you indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** this answer [Milliseconds in POSIXct Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22037657/4421870) addresses what is happening with `POSIXct`

> (Note that you get rounding errors, and R's datetime formatting always rounds downwards, so if you show less decimal places it sometimes looks like you've lost a millisecond.)

---

The problem seems to exist with `ymd_hms` and also `as.POSIXct`.

If I call `strptime` directly, or use `as.POSIXlt`, the milliseconds parse correctly:

```
strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Europe/Helsinki")

as.POSIXlt(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Europe/Helsinki")
```

Either of those options should fix your problem.

```
"2019-01-14 10:58:23.438 EET"
```

`POSIXlt` and `POSIXct` are behaving differently however:

```
as.POSIXlt(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Europe/Helsinki") %>% 
  format(., "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")

[1] "2019-01-14 10:58:23.438000"

as.POSIXct(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Europe/Helsinki") %>% 
  format(., "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")

[1] "2019-01-14 10:58:23.437999"
```

Comment: doesn't seem that it truncates too much, as .123456 works normally to my understanding. Have to keep thinking.

Comment: Just edited with a link to another SO question that addresses it. Although I don't know that I'm satisfied with the answer that R is rounding somewhere when provided with a definite time that should have an exact decimal representation.

Comment: yeah, my problem is that I'm working in tibble and it won't allow POSIXlt format.

Comment: @Hakki also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788598/4421870). It sounds like may really be a floating point issue, and unless you need accuracy beyond something like `1e-16`, it really shouldn't be a problem.